# Why isn't the utf8mb4 the default charset in mysql connector libraries like PySQLPool and MySQLdb. Does it have any overheads?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a MySQLDb. I want to set the default charset to utf8mb4. Are their any overheads to this.

Comment: Why it isn't the default? Well, isn't that a question for the vendor to answer? Overhead? For switching, or for using? For using: the utf8mb4 encoding will sometimes need to use a fourth byte (for chars not supported in MySql's utf8 encoding). So that potentially will use a fraction more space than before. But how often that happens, is really depending on the data you'll store.

Comment: @trincot but that is while storing, I am talking about passing the charset in the connection.
PySQLPool.PySQLConnection(.., charset='utf8mb4')
Is there any harm in that.

Comment: Is your database's character set `utf8mb4`?

Comment: @trincot one column on the database is?